# find the dimension of $V?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space of all continuous functions $f:[0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[0, 1]$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2$, the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[1, 2]$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$   Then find  the dimension of $V?$

**My attempt**:let us  take $f(x)=\begin{cases}a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 &\text{ if }x\in [0,1]\\a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 &\text{ if }x \in [1,2]\end{cases}$

and let $g_1(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$  and $g_2(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$

Also, $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$

Here $C([0,1] , \mathbb{R})$ is  a vector space

$$C([0,1] , \mathbb{R})=\Bigl\{  f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} |  \text{f is  continious and } f(x)=\begin{cases}g_1(x) &\text{ if }x\in [0,1]\\g_2(x) &\text{ if }x \in [1,2]\end{cases} \Bigr\}$$

Now  we have to find the   dimension of V

Here $f = g_1+g_2=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+  a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$

$f(x)=2a_0+2a_x+2a_2x^2 +x^3$

$\deg f(x)= 3$  therefore the   dimension of  $V$ is $ 4$

Am  i right ?

Comment: Why would the constant and linear terms need to match?  Granted you need $g_1(1)=g_2(1)$ for continuity, though you don't seem to consider that constraint.

Comment: Both are polynomials @lulu

Comment: Yes....so what?

Comment: Also the end doesn't make that much sense: You are not interested in the degree of the polynomial, but in the degree of freedom when choosing $f$.

The writing $f=g_1+g_2$ doesn't really make sense as it's piecewise defined as $g_1$ on one interval and as $g_2$ on another

Comment: To be sure:  there's no need for $f(x)$ to be a polynomial. For instance, the function $f(x)$ which is $1+x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $x^2+x^3$ for $x\in [1,2]$ is in your space $V$.

Comment: The argumentation should be like: Every $f$ in $V$ has $7$ freely choosable parameters, thus the dimension of $V$ should be $7$. Just like in the "typical" 3D-vector space where you can choose every coordinate $\left(\begin{array} aa \\ b \\c\end{array}\right)$ individually $\Rightarrow$ dimension is $3$

Comment: @LegNaiB  Continuity is a constraint.  Kills one dimension.

Comment: @lulu You mean  $\ deg f=  \deg g_1  + \deg g_2?$

Comment: No.  Why would you think that? It's not even clear what you mean by the degree of $f$.

Comment: @lulu  $f$   contain   two  different functions    so  i think $\deg f $is the max $\{g_1,g_2\}$

Comment: Your function f is not a polynomial so you cannot assign a „polynomial“ degree to it… Did you try forcing your f to be continuous at 1 to see what you’d get? It’s rally the most crucial thing in the question and so far it has been ignored.

Comment: @T.P. function is  continious  so  it is polynomial  because  polynomial $\implies$   continious

Comment: Polynomials are continuous but not all continuous functions are polynomials. For example, the trigonometric functions are continuous but not polynomials.

Comment: Please study the example I gave you:  Letting $g_1(x)=1+x$ and $g_2(x)=x^2+x^3$ gives you an element of $V$.  Check that!  Convince yourself that it is not a polynomial.  Another example might be $g_1(x)=0$ $g_2(x)=x^3-1$.  Again, confirm that this gives an element of $V$ which is not a polynomial.

Comment: @lulu oh I oversaw the "continuity" condition in the question :D Yes, then one needs to reduce the dimension by one